# angularjs ng-repeat inside ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-if

angular js ng-if inside ng-repeat not working
[My angularjs ng-if code](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/PQvQ2/)

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <div ng-repeat = "data in categories">
     <div ng-if="data.name == 'Sport' ">
          {{data.name}}
     </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What to want to do? In your fiddle it is not clear.

Comment: i have to  angularjs ng-if inside ng-repeat with the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle you're using AngularJS 1.0.6. `ng-if` was introduced from 1.1.5.
Change AngularJS version and your code will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/760/

If you really need 1.0.6 (not suggested at all) you can change `ng-if` to `ng-show`. It will hide the other elements, but I repeat, I don't suggest it. Please upgrade to a newer AngularJS version.